# What are the packages and libraries needed to print a file into pdf?

Tags: printing, lubuntu, pdf

Which packages and libraries are necessary to print a file into pdf file, especially a webpage, text file or an office document (spread sheet and word processor)? For instance, cups - is it necessary to have it?

PS: I have no hardware printer. I have an old laptop which I plan to make as lightweight as possible as it came across me.

Answer (score 2):

There should be a print to file feature by default
  [image]

Alternatively there is [cups-pdf](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/cups-pdf) that will add a PDF printer, PDF files will be saved to `~/PDF/`

  [image]

  [image]

Comment: But, does the print to file command need anything in specific?

Comment: no, in my exp it is just there, but you have to use file -> print to get it, the pdf printer will work with a quick print button